# Como saber se o arquivo está sendo usado por outro processo antes de tentar ler

Tags: c#

Meu sistema faz N trabalhos em cima de uma lista de arquivos, eventualmente eu recebo essa exceção:

> System.IO.IOException: O processo não pode acessar o arquivo
>   'C:\XXXXXX\xxxx.xxx' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.

O código que lança a exceção é:

```
if (File.ReadAllBytes(file).Length > 0 )
{
   ...
}
```

Existe alguma forma de eu saber se ele está sendo usado antes de executar o `ReadAllBytes`? Existe alguma outra solução? Ler de outra forma?

Eu sei que isso acontece porque alguma outra rotina minha deve está dando `lock` no arquivo, mas isso é eventual, uma em *5000* vezes. Por isso estou tendo dificuldades em conseguir uma solução.

Comment: "Eu sei que isso acontece porque alguma outra rotina minha deve está dando lock no arquivo" - então existem várias threads a acederem ao mesmo ficheiro? Então a solução é encontrar a race condition e sincronizar devidamente as threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De forma simples, você pode trabalhar com o arquivo num bloco `Try/Catch`, na ocorrência de exceções, por exemplo `IOException`, voce verifica o código de erro retornado, se for `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` ou `ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION`, o arquivo está em uso.

Conforme [está resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3202085/1608936), você pode implementar isto da seguinte forma:

```
public bool ArquivoEmUso (string arquivo) {
    try {
        using (File.Open(arquivo, FileMode.Open)) {}
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        var errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(e) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
        return errorCode == 32 || errorCode == 33;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Uma outra forma, mais apropriada, é utilizar a [API **Restart Manager**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/restart-manager-portal), Segundo a [página *Como faço para descobrir qual processo tem um arquivo aberto?*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283), *em inglês*, o objetivo desta API é:

> O objetivo oficial da *Restart Manager* é ajudar a tornár possível
> desligar e reiniciar os aplicativos que estão usando um arquivo que
> você deseja atualizar.
>
> A fim de fazer isso, ele precisa manter o controle de quais processos
> estão segurando as referências a quais arquivos. [...]

[**Está resposta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623302/1608936) do SOEN sugere implementar isto da seguinte forma:

```
static public class FileUtil {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS {
        public int dwProcessId;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ProcessStartTime;
    }

    const int RmRebootReasonNone = 0;
    const int CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME = 255;
    const int CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME = 63;

    enum RM_APP_TYPE {
        RmUnknownApp = 0, RmMainWindow = 1, RmOtherWindow = 2, RmService = 3,
        RmExplorer = 4, RmConsole = 5, RmCritical = 1000
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    struct RM_PROCESS_INFO {
        public RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS Process;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME + 1)]
        public string strAppName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME + 1)]
        public string strServiceShortName;

        public RM_APP_TYPE ApplicationType;
        public uint AppStatus;
        public uint TSSessionId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool bRestartable;
    }

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int RmRegisterResources(uint pSessionHandle,
                                          UInt32 nFiles,
                                          string[] rgsFilenames,
                                          UInt32 nApplications,
                                          [In] RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS[] rgApplications,
                                          UInt32 nServices,
                                          string[] rgsServiceNames);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int RmStartSession(out uint pSessionHandle, int dwSessionFlags, 
                                     string strSessionKey);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    static extern int RmEndSession(uint pSessionHandle);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    static extern int RmGetList(uint dwSessionHandle,
                                out uint pnProcInfoNeeded,
                                ref uint pnProcInfo,
                                [In, Out] RM_PROCESS_INFO[] rgAffectedApps,
                                ref uint lpdwRebootReasons);

    /// <summary>
    /// Encontra quais processo(s) têm um bloqueio no arquivo especificado
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Caminho do arquivo</param>
    /// <returns>Processo(s) que bloqueiam o arquivo</returns>
    /// <remarks>Veja também:
    /// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373661(v=vs.85).aspx
    /// http://wyupdate.googlecode.com/svn-history/r401/trunk/frmFilesInUse.cs
    /// </remarks>
    static public List<Process> WhoIsLocking(string path) {
        uint handle;
        string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();

        int res = RmStartSession(out handle, 0, key);
        if (res != 0) 
          throw new Exception("Não foi possível iniciar a sessão de reinício. Não foi possível determinar arquivo bloqueador.");

        try {
            const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
            uint pnProcInfoNeeded = 0,
                 pnProcInfo = 0,
                 lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone;

            // Apenas verificando em um recurso
            string[] resources = new string[] { path };

            res = RmRegisterResources(handle, (uint)resources.Length, resources, 0, null, 0, null);

            if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Não foi possível registrar o recurso.");

            //Nota: Há uma condição de corrida aqui - a primeira chamada de RmGetList() 
            //retorna o número total de processos. No entanto, quando chamamos RmGetList()
            //novamente para obter os processos reais, este número pode ter aumentado.
            res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, null, ref lpdwRebootReasons);

            if (res == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
                // Criar um array para armazenar os resultados
                RM_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfo = new RM_PROCESS_INFO[pnProcInfoNeeded];
                pnProcInfo = pnProcInfoNeeded;

                // Obtém a lista 
                res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, processInfo, ref lpdwRebootReasons);
                if (res == 0) {
                    processes = new List<Process>((int)pnProcInfo);

                    //Enumerar todos os resultados e adiciona na lista a ser devolvida
                    for (int i = 0; i < pnProcInfo; i++) {
                        try {
                            processes.Add(Process.GetProcessById(processInfo[i].Process.dwProcessId));
                        }
                        //Capturar o erro - no caso de o processo não está sendo executado
                        catch (ArgumentException) { }
                    }
                }
                else throw new Exception("Não foi possível listar os processos do recurso bloqueador.");
            }
            else if (res != 0) throw new Exception("Não foi possível listar os processos de recurso bloqueador. Falha ao obter o tamanho do resultado.");
        }
        finally {
            RmEndSession(handle);
        }

        return processes;
    }
}
```

É necessário incluir os *namespaces*:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string arquivo = @"C:\Path\Do\Arquivo";
    List<Process> processos = FileUtil.WhoIsLocking(arquivo);

    foreach (Process processo in processos) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("O arquivo {0} está em uso!", Path.GetFileName(arquivo)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Nome do Processo {0}, PID: {1}", processo.ProcessName, processo.Id));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nota**: A [API `Restart Manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/restart-manager-portal) está disponível a partir do Windows Server *2008* e Windows Vista.

Artigo sobre o assunto: [**Restart Manager and Generic Method Compilation** - MSDN Magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/april/net-matters-restart-manager-and-generic-method-compilation)

Answer (score 3):

As boas práticas de I/O ditam que não se deve verificar se o ficheiro está em uso antes de o abrir, porque essa verificação seria inútil.

Por exemplo, dado o seguinte pseudo-codigo:

```
if(File.IsNotBeingUsed(filename))
    var file = File.Open(filename);
```

Nada impede um outro processo de, paralelamente, abrir o ficheiro entre a chamada a `IsNotBeingUsed` e a chamada a `File.Open`.

A mesma lógica aplica-se a verificar se um ficheiro existe antes de o abrir - nada impede outro processo de apagar paralelamente o ficheiro entre o momento em que fazemos a verificação e o momento em que o tentamos abrir.

Abre simplesmente o ficheiro e apanha a excepção se alguma for lançada.