# Ler um texto especifico dentro de um .txt no c#

Tags: c#, string

Preciso ler um arquivo de texto que contém várias linhas:

```
1            C0000000000                       132008281               
06140214     080515                            0000000005990 
00000000000000000000000000000000000599000000000000000000000000000
```

Preciso pegar apenas o valor `132008281` e coloca-lo em uma variável, apenas esse valor.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
//cria uma lista para armazenar os dados encontrados no documento
List<string> dados = new List<string>();
// indica qual o caminho do documento
string filePath = CaminhoArquivo;
//declara uma variável para receber linha por linha do doc
string linha;
//verifica se existe um doc com o nome passado ates de fazer a leitura
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
       //usa uma biblioteca chamada StreamReader para fazer a leitura do arquivo baseado no caminho informado
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
       {
           //cria um loop para adicionar linha por linha do doc até sua ultima linha
           while ((linha = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
               //adiciona linha a linha a nossa lista de dados
               dados.Add(linha);
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < dados.Count; i++)
       {
           Leiturax += dados[i].ToString()+"\n";
       }   
       Leiturax = Leiturax;
}
else
{
       //caso não encontre nenhum registro da a mensagem abaixo
       MessageBox.Show("Nenhum registro encontrado!", "Lendo Arquivo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Esse código cria um `Array`, mas preciso pegar apenas aquele trecho do texto.
 Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Existe algum padrão que seja comum no trecho que você quer pegar? você quer pegar somente esse valor no arquivo todo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue o código para procurar sempre o terceiro valor (separado por espaço em branco) de cada linha, e adicionar a uma lista `valoresEncontrados`.

```
List<string> valoresEncontrados = new List<string>();

try
{
    string[] lst = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        string[] linha = item.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (linha.Length >= 3)
        {
            valoresEncontrados.Add(linha[2]);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: e se ao invés de usar uma lista eu usar uma Datatable. Como ficaria?

Comment: Com Datatable fica um pouco mais complexo, mas podes dar uma olhada [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx), ou converter uma List para Datatable como [aqui](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o código é auto-explicativo

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

try
{
    var valores = File.ReadLines(filePath)
                      .Select(line => line.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                      .Where(split => split.Length >= 3)
                      .Select(split => split[2])
                      .ToList();

}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    //mostrar erro
}
```

Nota: não adianta verificar se o ficheiro existe com `File.Exists` antes de o abrir, vê [a explicação aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65584/2360). Abre simplesmente o ficheiro, e depois apanha a excepção.

Comment: dcastro Obrigado pela resposta. O arquivo já está aberto.

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes De nada! Funcionou? Se sim, não te esqueças de marcar a resposta como correcta :)

Comment: Não amigo, ele pegou outra parte do texto.

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Qual parte? O texto que colocaste na pergunta é uma cópia exacta do ficheiro que estás a usar?

Comment: O documento pode varias linhas, uma ou varias, preciso dos textos que aparecem nas 3ª colunas.

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Devias esclarecer melhor na pergunta então. Na pergunta, só disseste "Preciso pegar apenas o valor 132008281" - isso é muito diferente de "preciso dos textos que aparecem nas 3ª colunas"

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Editei a resposta, agora vai obter os valores na 3a coluna. Experimenta outra vez