# Finalizar um processo sem fechar o executável

Tags: c#, exceção

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema integrado com um TEF. Toda vez que uma transação do cartão de credito é realizada o TEF cria um arquivo com um nome especificado em um diretório especifico, minha aplicação lê este arquivo e efetua a baixa e imprime o recibo. 
Acontece em momentos aleatórios o sistema me da uma exceção:

> System.IO.IOException: O processo não pode acessar o arquivo
>   'C:\XXXXXX\xxxx.xxx' porque ele está sendo usado por outro processo.

estou usando a `API Restart Manager` pra verificar se o arquivo já está em uso, porém ao identificar que sim, como quem está usando o arquivo é a própria aplicação, eu não posso fazer `processo.Kill()` pois ele irá fechar minha própria aplicação.

Sempre depois que eu uso o arquivo eu estou colocando `arquivo.close()`.

Não entendo por que ainda fica executando.

```
try {
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath);
  line = sr.ReadLine();
  while (line != null)
  {
    //Código da para armazenas as informações importantes em variáveis
    line = sr.ReadLine();
  }
  sr.Close();
} catch (Exception a) {
  // mensagem da exceção
}
```

Consigo ver qual o processo está usando o mesmo arquivo que estou tentando ler, fiz baseado nesta resposta:
[Como saber se o arquivo está sendo usado por outro processo antes de tentar ler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65560/como-saber-se-o-arquivo-est%C3%A1-sendo-usado-por-outro-processo-antes-de-tentar-ler)

Preciso encerrar este processo e/ou fechar o arquivo que foi aberto pelo outro processo, sem encerrar a aplicação

Comment: Pode ser que ele esteja aberto e sendo acessado por outro processo.

Comment: pode postar parte do código para analisarmos ?

Comment: Sim com certeza está, so que o outro processo é da minha propria aplicação, que de alguma forma não finalizou, como posso forçar que esse processo seja finalizado sem fechar minha aplicação?

Comment: @jonathan Use o botão **Editar** abaixo da sua pergunta para incluir novas informações /códigos para melhorar a sua pergunta. Os comentários não são um bom lugar para isso.  Alias, seja bem vindo ao SOPT!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Recomendo também: [ASK] e [TOUR].  Essas páginas contém algumas recomendações para fazermos boas perguntas.

Comment: Ultilize o finally. try{ tenta,... } catch (Exception e) { //pega o erro } finally { apos tudo e antes do return sr.Close(); }

Comment: mudei o sr.close() pra imediatamente antes do return e inclui o finally, vou aguardar pois o erro ocorre depois de um grande numero de transações, se funcionar eu aviso aqui.

Comment: Não seria o caso de escrever seu aplicativo como um serviço?

Comment: Infelizmente mesmo mudando o close() pra antes do return de lugar e inserindo o finally, o problema ainda persiste.

Comment: @jonathan Você cria esse, arquivo e logo depois lê? será que ele não está ficando aberto na própria criação?

Comment: quem cria o arquivo e uma segunda aplicação, que controla o TEF, eu faço uma leitura no diretório, e fico aguardando a criação do arquivo quando o arquivo e criado com o nome que eu estou esperando, eu leio ele

Comment: @jonathan sua aplicação é windows form ou web, ou nenhum dos dois ? (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer a leitura do arquivo usando um FileStream e um StreamReader especificando os acessos ao invés do construtor padrão. Isto talvez resolva:

```
    public string Executa(string caminho)
    {
        var conteudo = new StringBuilder();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
            {
                var linha = streamReader.ReadLine();
                while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linha))
                {
                    //Código da para armazenas as informações importantes em variáveis
                    conteudo.AppendLine(linha);

                    linha = streamReader.ReadLine();
                }

                streamReader.Close();
            }
        }

        return conteudo.ToString();
    }
```

Testa aí e vê se resolve.